# Interesting Database Architecture Scenario

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am currently in the process of rolling a custom order-processing system. My current structure is pretty standard, invoices, purchase orders, and items are all kept in separate tables. Items know which form(s) they are on by keeping track of the form's id, but forms don't know what items are in them (in the database). This was all well and good until I had a new requirement added to the mix: stocking orders.

The way a stocking order works is that sometimes a customer places an order for more units than what is in stock, so we want to place an order with our supplier for enough units to fulfill the order and replenish our stock. However, we often have to build these orders up as the minimums are pretty high, so one stocking order is usually comprised of several customer orders (sometimes for the same item) PLUS a few line items that are NOT connected to an order and are just for stocking purposes.

This presents a problem with my current architecture because I now need to keep track of what comes in from the stocking orders as often suppliers ship partial orders, where items have been allocated, and which incoming items are for stock.

My initial idea was to create a new database table that mostly mimics the items table, but is kind of like an aggregate (but not calculated) table that only keeps track of the items and their corresponding metadata (how many units received, how many for stock, etc) for only the stocking orders. I would have to keep the two tables in synch if something changed from one of them (like a quantity).

Is this overkill, and maybe there's a better way to do it? Database architecture is definitely not my forte, so I was hoping that someone could either tell me that this is an ok way to do things or that there is a better, more correct way to do it.

Thanks so much!

For what it's worth, what I'm using: VB, .NET 4.0, MySQL 5.0

Also, if you want clarification on anything, please ask! I will be closely monitoring this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit databaseanswers.com.  Navigate to "free data models",  and look for "Inventory Management".  You should find some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

you didnt mention them but you will need tables for:
SUPPLIERS, ORDERS, and INVENTORY

also, the base tables you mention 'knowing about' - these probably need associative style many to many tables which tell you things like which items are on which order, and which suppliers supply which items, lead times, costs etc.

it would be helpful to see your actual schema.

Comment: thanks, yeah i have a suppliers and orders table... i definitely should break out my inventory into its own separate table. right now it's kind of piggybacking on the products table. i have costs, which suppliers supply which items, but we never really know lead times. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use a single Documents table, with a DocType field. Client documents (Order, Invoice, ProForma, Delivery, Credit Notes) are mixed with Suppliers documents (PO, Reception).
This makes it quite easy to calculate Client backorders, Supplier backorders, etc...
I am just a bit unhappy because I have different tables for SUPPLIERS and CLIENTS, and therefore the DOCUMENTS table has both a SupplierId field and a ClientId field, which is a bit bad. If I had to redo it I might consider a single Companies table containing both Clients and Suppliers.

I use a PK (DocId) that's autoincrement, and a unique key (DocNum) that's like XYY00000, with
x= doc type
YY= year
00000 = increment.
This is because a doc can be saved but is only at validation time it receives a DocNum.

To track backorders (Supplier or Client), you will need to have a Grouping field in the DocDetails table, so that if you have an Order line 12345, you copy that Link field to every Detail line related to it (invoice, Delivery).
Hope I am not to confusing. The thing works well, after 3 years and over 50,000 docs.

Answer (score 0):

This approach also implies that you will have a stock holding which is allocated for orders - without individual item tracking its a bit tricky to manage this. Consider, customer A orders

```
3 pink widgets
1 blue widget
```

But you only have 1 pink widget in stock - you order 3 pink widgets, and 1 blue.

Customer B orders

```
2 pink widgets
```

But you've still only got 1 in stock - you order another pink widget

3 pink widgets arrive from the first supplier order. What are you going to do? You can either reserve all of them for customer A's order and wait for the blue and red widget to arrive, or you can fulfill customer B's order.

What if the lead time on a pink widget is 3 days and for a blue widget it's 3 weeks? Do you ship partial orders to your customers? Do you have a limit on the amount of stock you will hold?

Just keeping a new table of backorders is not going to suffice.

This stuff gets scary complicated really quickly. You certainly need to spend a lot more time analysing the problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer... i'm aware of the complexities of the ordering process. it's definitely scary when you have stupid long backorder times. usually what we do when we bring in items for stock is bring in a lot of them, so say we have 2 units in stock of something and someone orders three, we'll order like 20 from the factory. do you have some sort of solution?